# I am trying to migrate mercurial repos to gitlab in windows machine by using hg-fast-export tool, its throwing an error

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to migrate mercurial repos to GitLab in windows machine by using hg-fast-export tool,      packages installed Python-2.7.16 and mercurial 4.6.1. its throwing an error.

export tool repo iam using: https://github.com/frej/fast-export.git

error message:

```
  C:\Projects\Git\test_repo\hg2git.py", line 47, in setup repo
          
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mercurial\scmutil.py", line 1031, in readrequires
  hint=_("see https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MissingRequirement"
mercurial . error . Requirement Error : repository requires features unknown to this Mercurial: share-safe
fast-import statistics:
```

Thanks in Advance. Any answer or method would be appreciated.

Tried with updating versions and some solutions from other sites, but didn't work. Expecting correct repo and solution.

Comment: mercurial.error.RequirementError: repository requires features unknown to this Mercurial: share-safe
\hg2git.py", line 47, in setup_repo
    return myui,hg.repository(myui, fsencode(url)).unfiltered()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mercurial\hg.py", line 179, in repository
    intents=intents)
hg-fast-export.py", line 519, in hg2git
    ui,repo=setup_repo(repourl)

Comment: Just edit your question with new info, don't add it as a comment.